# PHP array structure change

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

This shouldn't be confusing me as much as it is but I am looking to turn this:

```
array:3 [▼
  "subject" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "math"
        1 => "english"
  ]
 "grade" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "a"
      1 => "b"
  ]
  "received" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "2017"
      1 => "2016"
  ]
]
```

into this:

```
array:2 [▼
  "0" => array:3 [▼
    "subject" => "math"
    "grade" => "a"
    "received" => "2017"
  ]
  "1" => array:3 [▼
    "subject" => "english"
    "grade" => "b"
    "received" => "2016"
  ]
]
```

Tried looping through in a couple different ways but never seem to get the result I am looking for, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How about you show one of the loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple Version:

```
$arr1 = array(...);
$arr2 = array();

foreach ($arr1 as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $x => $y) {
        $arr2[$x][$k] = $y;
    }
}
```

But you should add conditions, if the array element not exists, create it, or you may get Errors, depending on your PHP configuration.

Comment: Are you referring to `$arr2[$x][$k] = ...` creating errors? No, it never will. Implicit intermediate array creation is explicitly supported.

Answer (score 4):

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$result = array_map(
    function (...$values) use ($keys) { return array_combine($keys, $values); }, 
    ...array_values($array)
);
```

Which is essentially this, but less repetitive:

```
array_map(
    function ($subject, $grade, $received) {
        return [
            'subject' => $subject,
            'grade' => $grade, 
            'received' => $received
        ];
    },
    $array['subject'],
    $array['grade'],
    $array['received']
)
```

See the manual for [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`...`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) for more explanation.

Comment: First way threw an error "array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements" however 2nd answer worked perfectly, Thanks @deceze